# How to join these data frames in R into given format?

Tags: r, dataframe, join, dplyr, merge

I have the following two data frames in R:

1. Researchers and their working history

| LASTNAME | FIRSTNAMEINITIAL | STARTYEAR | ENDYEAR | POSITION |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Doe | J | 2019 | 2022 | Assistant Professor |
| Doe | J | 2022 | 2023 | Associate Professor |
| Doe | J | 2023 | Present | Full Professor |
| Potter | H | 2019 | 2022 | Assistant Professor |
| Potter | H | 2022 | Present | Associate Professor |
| ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |

2. Published journal articles

| TITLE | JOURNAL | PUBYEAR | AUTHORS |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ARTICLE 1 | JOURNAL 1 | 2020 | Poppins, M (Poppins, Mary); Doe, J (Doe, John); |
| ARTICLE 2 | JOURNAL 2 | 2021 | Pan, P (Pan, Peter); Potter, H (Potter, Harry); |
| ARTICLE 3 | JOURNAL 1 | 2021 | Doe, J (Doe, J); Baggins, B (Baggins, Bilbo); |
| ARTICLE 4 | JOURNAL 3 | 2021 | DOE, J (DOE, JOHN); POTTER, HJ (POTTER, HARRY JAMES); |
| ARTICLE 5 | JOURNAL 2 | 2023 | Hamilton, L (Hamilton, Lewis); Doe, J (Doe, John); Woods, T (Woods, Tiger); |
| ... | ... | ... | ... |

I want to create the following data frame:

| LASTNAME | FIRSTNAMEINITIAL | STARTYEAR | ENDYEAR | POSITION | ARTICLES |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Doe | J | 2019 | 2020 | Assistant Professor | 0 |
| Doe | J | 2020 | 2021 | Assistant Professor | 1 |
| Doe | J | 2021 | 2022 | Assistant Professor | 2 |
| Doe | J | 2022 | 2023 | Associate Professor | 0 |
| Doe | J | 2023 | 2024 | Full Professor | 1 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |

That is, for all uniquely identifiable researchers, make a row for each year of the researcher's working history supplemented with the number of articles that the researcher published during that year either alone or as one of the co-authors.

I tried to look up examples online but did not manage to crack the problem yet. So I guess there are at least 3 parts to this problem:

1. How to create a data frame having one row for each year in the researcher's working history, even if the researcher might spend a different duration of years in each position?
2. How to map the researcher's last name and first name initial with the AUTHORS column in the publication data frame? In the resulting data frame, we don't want to include researchers, who have a non-unique/non-identifiable name (Potter, H in my example data). The reason is that in this case, we cannot be sure whether Potter, HJ in the publication data frame is truly the same person as Potter, H. Therefore, we only want to include researchers, who have a unique combination of the last name and the first name initial letter in the published data frame
3. After the mapping, how to calculate the number of articles for each year?

I would appreciate any help with this problem!

Comment: are `Doe, J` and `Doe, JE` the same person?

Comment: Very likely, so you can assume yes. However, I might want to flag these ambiguous cases to possibly remove them from the sample. later on. There can arguably be people with the same last name and the same first name initial, so I would not want to calculate the wrong number of published articles for them.

Comment: If it is easier for the solution, all these ambiguous cases can be removed upfront as well. My analysis does not depend on having each person in the sample.

Answer (score 4):

Since `Doe, J` and `Doe, JE` are possibly the same person, two extra things (from the first version of this answer):

- use of `fuzzyjoin` to do a regex match; for this, I'll ramp up a bit so that both sides are considered a pattern against the other ... and I haven't thought through completely where this is likely to fail, caveat emptor
- add another field (`OtherMatches`) to show which authors were matches ...

```r
library(dplyr)
library(fuzzyjoin) # fuzzy_left_join
library(tidyr)     # separate_longer_delim

published2a <- published2 %>%
  separate_longer_delim(AUTHORS, delim = ";") %>%
  mutate(AUTHORS = trimws(sub(" *\\(.*", "", AUTHORS))) %>%
  filter(!is.na(AUTHORS), nzchar(AUTHORS))
published2a
#        TITLE   JOURNAL PUBYEAR     AUTHORS
# 1  ARTICLE 1 JOURNAL 1    2020  Poppins, M
# 2  ARTICLE 1 JOURNAL 1    2020      Doe, J
# 3  ARTICLE 2 JOURNAL 2    2021      Pan, P
# 4  ARTICLE 2 JOURNAL 2    2021  Potter, HJ
# 5  ARTICLE 3 JOURNAL 1    2021      Doe, J
# 6  ARTICLE 3 JOURNAL 1    2021  Baggins, B
# 7  ARTICLE 4 JOURNAL 3    2021     Doe, JE
# 8  ARTICLE 5 JOURNAL 2    2023 Hamilton, L
# 9  ARTICLE 5 JOURNAL 2    2023      Doe, J
# 10 ARTICLE 5 JOURNAL 2    2023    Woods, T

out <- researchers %>%
  mutate(
    ENDYEAR = if_else(ENDYEAR == "Present", 2024L, suppressWarnings(as.integer(ENDYEAR)))
  ) %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  reframe(
    LASTNAME, FIRSTNAMEINITIAL,
    LASTFIRST = paste(LASTNAME, FIRSTNAMEINITIAL, sep = ", "),
    STARTYEAR = seq(STARTYEAR, max(STARTYEAR, ENDYEAR - 1)),
    ENDYEAR   = seq(min(STARTYEAR + 1, ENDYEAR), ENDYEAR),
    POSITION
  ) %>%
  fuzzyjoin::fuzzy_left_join(
    published2a,
    by = c(LASTFIRST = "AUTHORS", STARTYEAR = "PUBYEAR", ENDYEAR = "PUBYEAR"),
    match_fun = list(
      function(v1, v2) stringr::str_detect(v1, stringr::regex(v2, ignore_case = TRUE)) |
                         stringr::str_detect(v2, stringr::regex(v1, ignore_case = TRUE)),
      `<=`,
      `>`
    )
  ) %>%
  reframe(
    ARTICLES = sum(!is.na(TITLE)),
    CloseMatches = list(na.omit(setdiff(unique(AUTHORS), LASTFIRST))),
    .by = names(researchers))
out
# # A tibble: 5 × 7
#   LASTNAME FIRSTNAMEINITIAL STARTYEAR ENDYEAR POSITION            ARTICLES CloseMatches
#   <chr>    <chr>                <int>   <int> <chr>                  <int> <list>      
# 1 Doe      J                     2019    2020 Assistant Professor        0 <chr [0]>   
# 2 Doe      J                     2020    2021 Assistant Professor        1 <chr [0]>   
# 3 Doe      J                     2021    2022 Assistant Professor        2 <chr [1]>   
# 4 Doe      J                     2022    2023 Associate Professor        0 <chr [0]>   
# 5 Doe      J                     2023    2024 Full Professor             1 <chr [0]>   
str(out$CloseMatches)
# List of 5
#  $ : chr(0) 
#   ..- attr(*, "na.action")= 'omit' int 1
#  $ : chr(0) 
#  $ : chr "Doe, JE"
#  $ : chr(0) 
#   ..- attr(*, "na.action")= 'omit' int 1
#  $ : chr(0)
```

Brief walkthrough:

- clean up `published2` (as opposed to the original `published` from before) so that the authors are one-line per, removing empties and the parenthetic stuff we don't need at the moment;
- we need `ENDYEAR` to be integer, so we'll convert `"Present"` to 2024 (inferring) and convert the remaining;
- per row, we "reframe" a row to expand from one or more years per row to one year per row;
- join that longer `published` back onto the original data by author and within the year range, using various criteria: the names are joining using `stringr::str_detect` with both sides (from `researchers` and `published2a`) as the pattern, this might prove to be too aggressive, again caveat emptor
- count rows with non-`NA` values in `TITLE`; for years where no articles were published, the `TITLE` will be `NA`, summing to `0`; simultaneously, produce a vector of names that are not a precise match of the original in `researchers`;

This requires dplyr-1.1.0 or newer (for `reframe`).

---

*Edit*: since your data is a bit big, we can break up the regex-joining, perhaps this will allow it to work for you.

First, pre-pivot both frames to long format:

```r
published2_long <- published2 %>%
  separate_longer_delim(AUTHORS, delim = ";") %>%
  mutate(AUTHORS = trimws(sub(" *\\(.*", "", AUTHORS))) %>%
  filter(!is.na(AUTHORS), nzchar(AUTHORS))

researchers_long <- researchers %>%
  mutate(
    ENDYEAR = if_else(ENDYEAR == "Present", 2024L, suppressWarnings(as.integer(ENDYEAR)))
  ) %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  reframe(
    LASTNAME, FIRSTNAMEINITIAL,
    LASTFIRST = toupper(paste(LASTNAME, FIRSTNAMEINITIAL, sep = ", ")),
    STARTYEAR = seq(STARTYEAR, max(STARTYEAR, ENDYEAR - 1)),
    ENDYEAR   = seq(min(STARTYEAR + 1, ENDYEAR), ENDYEAR),
    POSITION,
    ARTICLES = 0, CloseMatches = list(list())
  )
```

Now iterate over groups of rows of `published2_long`; I'm sloppily using `5` for demonstration here, you should find a number that works well for you.

```r
for (rn in split(1:nrow(published2_long), 1:nrow(published2_long) %/% 5)) {
  researchers_long <- fuzzyjoin::fuzzy_left_join(
    researchers_long,
    published2_long[rn,],
    by = c(LASTFIRST = "AUTHORS", STARTYEAR = "PUBYEAR", ENDYEAR = "PUBYEAR"),
    match_fun = list(
      function(v1, v2) stringr::str_detect(v1, stringr::regex(v2, ignore_case = TRUE)) |
                         stringr::str_detect(v2, stringr::regex(v1, ignore_case = TRUE)),
      `<=`,
      `>`
    )
  ) %>%
    summarize(ARTICLES = ARTICLES[1] + sum(!is.na(TITLE)),
              .by = names(researchers_long))
}
researchers_long
# # A tibble: 5 × 8
#   LASTNAME FIRSTNAMEINITIAL LASTFIRST STARTYEAR ENDYEAR POSITION            ARTICLES CloseMatches
#   <chr>    <chr>            <chr>         <int>   <int> <chr>                  <dbl> <list>      
# 1 Doe      J                DOE, J         2019    2020 Assistant Professor        0 <list [0]>  
# 2 Doe      J                DOE, J         2020    2021 Assistant Professor        1 <list [0]>  
# 3 Doe      J                DOE, J         2021    2022 Assistant Professor        2 <list [0]>  
# 4 Doe      J                DOE, J         2022    2023 Associate Professor        0 <list [0]>  
# 5 Doe      J                DOE, J         2023    2024 Full Professor             1 <list [0]>
```

---

Data

```r
researchers <- structure(list(LASTNAME = c("Doe", "Doe", "Doe"), FIRSTNAMEINITIAL = c("J", "J", "J"), STARTYEAR = c(2019L, 2022L, 2023L), ENDYEAR = c("2022", "2023", "Present"), POSITION = c("Assistant Professor", "Associate Professor", "Full Professor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))
published <- structure(list(TITLE = c("ARTICLE 1", "ARTICLE 2", "ARTICLE 3", "ARTICLE 4", "ARTICLE 5"), JOURNAL = c("JOURNAL 1", "JOURNAL 2", "JOURNAL 1", "JOURNAL 3", "JOURNAL 2"), PUBYEAR = c(2020L, 2021L, 2021L, 2021L, 2023L), AUTHORS = c("POPPINS, M; DOE, J;", "PAN, P; POTTER, H;", "DOE, J; BAGGINS, B;", "DOE, J;", "HAMILTON, L; DOE, J; WOODS, T;")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L))
published2 <- structure(list(TITLE = c("ARTICLE 1", "ARTICLE 2", "ARTICLE 3", "ARTICLE 4", "ARTICLE 5"), JOURNAL = c("JOURNAL 1", "JOURNAL 2", "JOURNAL 1", "JOURNAL 3", "JOURNAL 2"), PUBYEAR = c(2020L, 2021L, 2021L, 2021L, 2023L), AUTHORS = c("Poppins, M (Poppins, Mary); Doe, J (Doe, John);", "Pan, P (Pan, Peter); Potter, HJ (Potter, Harry James);", "Doe, J (Doe, J); Baggins, B (Baggins, Bilbo);", "Doe, JE (DOE, JOHN EDWARD);", "Hamilton, L (Hamilton, Lewis); Doe, J (Doe, John); Woods, T (Woods, Tiger);")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA,  -5L))
```

Comment: Instead of `rowwise() %>%
  reframe(
    LASTNAME, FIRSTNAMEINITIAL,
    LASTFIRST = toupper(paste(LASTNAME, FIRSTNAMEINITIAL, sep = ", ")),
    STARTYEAR = seq(STARTYEAR, max(STARTYEAR, ENDYEAR - 1)),
    ENDYEAR   = seq(min(STARTYEAR + 1, ENDYEAR), ENDYEAR),
    POSITION
  ) %>%` you could `YEAR = purrr::map2(STARTYEAR, ENDYEAR, ~seq(.x, .y - 1))
  ) %>%
  unnest(YEAR) %>%
  mutate(
    LASTFIRST = toupper(paste(LASTNAME, FIRSTNAMEINITIAL, sep = ", "))
  )` I was on the right way but then I lost track!. Good work!

Comment: That can work too, thanks @TarJae!

Comment: Great! This is nearly perfect. However, the names in the AUTHORS column of the researchers data frame were not exactly as simple as my mock data frames suggest. There are 2 problems: 1) the values of the AUTHORS column name may sometimes have additional letters to indicate the researcher's full name 2) The AUTHORS value has parentheses to indicate the unabbreviated name if available. To show these problems, here is an example value with hypothetical names but in exactly the same format as the real data: "Doe JE (Doe, John Edward); Potter, HJ (Potter, Harry James); Baggins, B (Baggins, Bilbo);"

Comment: In addition, some rows have AUTHORS in caps lock, others do not. I realize now it would have been wiser to give the full details in the prompt to solve all the problems at once. I will edit my question.

Comment: I feared as much, @EulersNumber. Yes, that is important and should be given up front, and ... it complicates things significantly. You can precondition all data so that `FIRSTNAMEINITIAL` is never a name, always an initial, and it may take testing to make sure you "get it good enough" to not miss things. Another method might use `fuzzyjoin::regex_left_join`, assuming that the patterns are simple-enough; using that function _well_ (resilient to false-pos/neg) takes some time and attention to detail, as false-positives are difficult to detect when you immediately aggregate into a count.

Comment: I understand and apologize. To simplify things a bit, could you provide a solution, where the ambiguous cases (e.g., "Doe, J" and "Doe JE") are ignored, but all persons with a unique combination of the last name and the first name initial (if several first names, then initial of only the first name) are included in the output?

Comment: see my edit @EulersNumber, I think this is a lot closer to what you need

Comment: The published2 data frame is in my instance of shape (224251, 24). Therefore, I get a memory allocation error: "Error in stri_detect_regex(string, pattern, negate = negate, opts_regex = opts(pattern)) : memory allocation error: failed to allocate 10013568768 bytes". Would it be easier to just drop the ambiguous ones from the published2 data frame and then map using only the LASTFIRST (I.e., last name and first initial of first name(s)). Can you come up with this solution?

Comment: Ha! Yes, you'll likely need to precondition, prefilter/reduce. If that is insufficient, consider running this in _batches_ of `published2`, where each result you then merge into `out` and add the new values to the previous values.

Comment: @EulersNumber, see my recent edit for batching it, hope it helps.

Comment: @r2evans I appreciate all your efforts thus far. Especially as it seems I was not that aware of the problem I really wanted to solve in the first place. Your latest suggestion does not really work, because the program ran all night and did not finish. I think at this point I simply want to exclude non-unique researchers and then do the simple mapping with e.g., FIRSTLAST. I edited my question such that Potter, H and Potter, HJ are the non-unique persons I would want to remove from the sample. Any chance this refined problem is easier to solve for you? I'd appreciate an effort yet again!

Answer (score 0):

```r
library(stringr)
library(data.table)
library(reshape2)

# How to create a data frame having one row for each year in the researcher's 
# working history, even if the researcher might spend a different duration of 
# years in each position?
profs_df <- read.delim(textConnection('LASTNAME FIRSTNAMEINITIAL    STARTYEAR   ENDYEAR POSITION
Doe J   2019    2022    Assistant Professor
Doe J   2022    2023    Associate Professor
Doe J   2023    Present Full Professor'))

# create a row for each year in a position
idx <- which(profs_df$ENDYEAR == 'Present')
profs_df[ idx, 'ENDYEAR' ] <- 2024L
profs_df <- apply(profs_df, 1, \(x) {
  sy <- as.integer(x[ 'STARTYEAR']):(as.integer(x[ 'ENDYEAR']) - 1)
  ey <- sy + 1
  data.frame(LASTNAME = x[ 'LASTNAME' ], 
             FIRSTNAMEINITIAL = x[ 'FIRSTNAMEINITIAL' ], 
             STARTYEAR = sy,
             ENDYEAR = ey,
             POSITION = x[ 'POSITION' ],
             row.names = NULL)
}) |> 
  rbindlist() |> 
  data.frame()

# How to map the researcher's last name and first name initial with the authors 
# in the publication data frame?
profs_df$AUTHOR <- sprintf('%s, %s',
                           profs_df$LASTNAME,
                           profs_df$FIRSTNAMEINITIAL) |> 
  toupper()

# After the mapping, how to calculate the number of articles for each year?
articles_df <- read.delim(textConnection('TITLE JOURNAL PUBYEAR AUTHORS
ARTICLE 1   JOURNAL 1   2020    POPPINS, M; DOE, J;
ARTICLE 2   JOURNAL 2   2021    PAN, P; POTTER, H;
ARTICLE 3   JOURNAL 1   2021    DOE, J; BAGGINS, B;
ARTICLE 4   JOURNAL 3   2021    DOE, J;
ARTICLE 5   JOURNAL 2   2023    HAMILTON, L; DOE, J; WOODS, T;'))

article_counts_df <- apply(articles_df, 1, \(x) {
  data.frame(AUTHOR = str_split(x[ 'AUTHORS' ], ';') |> 
               unlist() |> 
               setdiff(''), 
             YEAR = x[ 'PUBYEAR' ],
             row.names = NULL)
}) |> 
  rbindlist() |> 
  data.frame() |>
  table() |>
  melt()

# combine article count data with profs data
profs_df$ARTICLES <- apply(profs_df, 1, \(x) {
  idx <- which(article_counts_df$AUTHOR == x[ 'AUTHOR' ] &
                 article_counts_df$YEAR >= x[ 'STARTYEAR' ] &
                 article_counts_df$YEAR <= x[ 'ENDYEAR' ])
  article_counts_df[ idx, 'value' ] |> 
    sum(na.rm = TRUE)
})
profs_df$AUTHOR <- NULL

# print results
print(profs_df)
```

```
  LASTNAME FIRSTNAMEINITIAL STARTYEAR ENDYEAR            POSITION ARTICLES
1      Doe                J      2019    2020 Assistant Professor        0
2      Doe                J      2020    2021 Assistant Professor        2
3      Doe                J      2021    2022 Assistant Professor        2
4      Doe                J      2022    2023 Associate Professor        0
5      Doe                J      2023    2024      Full Professor        0
```